# getting error while uploading file to sharepoint via python

Tags: python, http, sharepoint, python-requests, office365

I want to upload file to my share point library but i got error 403 and this one return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 27227: character maps to 
Any one can help me please

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth('/user:example.com\\bingo','bingo', session)
sessionObj = requests.session()
url1='http://login.microsoftonline.com'
r = sessionObj.post(url1, params={'username':'bingo' , 'password':'bingo'})
print (r.status_code )
filename = 'test.xlsx'
file = open(filename, 'rb')
bytes = bytearray(file.read())
resp = requests.put('https://example.sharepoint.com/…/e…/Testing%20Reports/Forms/' + filename, data=bytes, auth=session.auth)
#url2='https://bentley.sharepoint.com/…/Testin…/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
#r = sessionObj.post(url2, data={},files = {'upload':file})
print (r.text)
```

Comment: `data = {'username':'bingo' , 'password':'bingo'})`

Comment: 403 Forbiden ERROR